# Good and easy books/tutorials to learn WCF latest stuff

Tags: wcf

Good and easy books/tutorials to learn WCF latest stuff

Comment: Thanks to every one for the help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308) by Juval Lowy

[IDesign.net](http://www.idesign.net) - Juval Lowy's website

[Keith Elder Demystifies WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=135) @ dnrTV

[Miguel Castro: Extreme WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) @ dnrTV

Answer (score 5):

The best book for beginner to intermediate level has to be:

Michele Leroux Bustamante, [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627)

[image: Learning WCF]

For more intermediate to advanced topics, Juval Lowy's [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308) is definitely **THE** book to check out.

[image: Programming WCF Services]

As for online tutorial - I don't really know many good ones. Lots of people blog about WCF, including [Michele Leroux Bustamante](http://dasblonde.net).

Check out some of those links here for tutorials on WCF:

- [WCF Step-by-step tutorial](http://www.xvpj.net/2008/03/08/wcf-step-by-step-tutorial/)
- [MSDN Getting started tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)
- [WCF Hello World Tutorial](http://dotnet.org.za/hiltong/articles/52518.aspx)

Marc

Comment: +1 Excellent book, not too large, you can quickly go through the relevant tutorials/chapters as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.wcf-training-guide.com/

[Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good introduction to WCF :

http://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2009/10/26/implement-a-contract-callback-using-a-oneway-method-in-wcf/

Answer (score 2):

First I want to point out a link that provides good background on WCF: http://en.csharp-online.net/WCF_Essentials.  The link did not show me how to use WCF in my own code, but the background information is good.

The tutorial I could work through is Microsoft's site.  I'm very much a beginner in WCF and following this tutorial I ended up with client and server (service provider) console applications that worked.

The one bit I did different was adding a service reference to the client program instead of using SvcUtil.exe.  To do that I had to run the server app outside of the IDE and enter the url (http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service) for the Visual Studio to locate the service and generate what it needed.

The tutorial is at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

Some of the other topics listed on part 6 of the tutorial are:

How to: Create a Windows Communication Foundation Client

How to: Create a Duplex Contract

How to: Access Services with a Duplex Contract

Building Windows Communication Foundation Clients

Getting Started Tutorial

Basic WCF Programming

Getting Started Sample

Self-Host