# C#: Instant Messager - Networking (.NET Remoting/WCF/Sockets)?

Tags: wcf, sockets, client, remoting

i'm going to build a instant messager 
and now i have to decide how i implement the networking.
So far i only worked with Sockets (TCP or UDP). Now i heared about RMI (in Java) and want this in my C#-Chatapplication too.

There is .NET Remoting and WCF. I think building the instant messager with Sockets is not a good idea, right? But that should i use? .NET Remoting or WCF?
.NET Remoting seems to be the older technologie and is similar to Java RMI.  I read that .NET Remoting is faster than WCT (article from 2007).

Which technologie should i use for my instant messager? I want to send formatted text from the richtextbox and inline images.
Furthermore i want to exchange files from chat-client to chat-client.

For .NET Remoting i found a tutorial which uses

```
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(myChan);
```

But this is marked as obsolete. Is .NET Remoting a obsolete technologie?
Is it possible to send images and files with WCF or .NET Remoting or are Sockets the better choice?

I read that WCF is a collection of networking technologies (Web Services, Remoting, ...) but if i search for WCF and remote method invocation i only get examples for Web Services...

BTW: Later, i want to implement a Web-Client for my instant messager with ASP.NET. Are there some limitations respective to Networking (WCF/Remoting)?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Remoting is maintained for backward compatibility only [as of .NET 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.85).aspx).  Thus, if you are going to be using .NET 3.0 or greater, use WCF.

For your immediate use, I would suggest the [`NetTcpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.nettcpbinding.aspx).  You can then select a more appropriate binding using the following chart.

[image: WCF Binding Selection Flow Chart].

Finally, to learn about WCF, refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343896/good-and-easy-books-tutorials-to-learn-wcf-latest-stuff).

Answer (score 1):

For your instant messager solution I would recommend **WCF P2P** here is an article to get you started [Peer-to-Peer Programming with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx) and here it is an example of p2p on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WPFWCF_Chat_App_via_P2P.aspx).

Comment: p2p ~ client to client? i want client/server-architecture with a DB (for users) :)