# Good books on Silverlight and WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

Can anyone suggest some good books that practically describe Silverlight and WCF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Book for Silverlight and WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311167/book-for-silverlight-and-wcf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for info of how to use SL for business apps (WCF RIA services...) [this one](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430272076) is a good one

Answer (score 0):

Wcf stuff:
[Good and easy books/tutorials to learn WCF latest stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343896/good-and-easy-books-tutorials-to-learn-wcf-latest-stuff)

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft Silverlight 4 Data and Services Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/microsoft-silverlight-4-data-and-services-cookbook/book) might be just what you need.